# Does PHP work for disabled HTML tags?

Tags: php

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked disabled /></td>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['chk'])) $chk = 1;
else $chk = 0;
```

But database gives `0` always. I need to set the database as `1`.

Comment: Your code and your question makes no sense at all! Please specify your problem more!

Comment: Please add brackets and styling

Comment: If you use `disabled` in your form element then `$_POST['chk']` will always be `null`.

Comment: No. disabled form fields are **NOT** submitted by the browser. This has nothing to do with PHP. It's standard browser behavior.

Comment: Why is this qusetion tagged MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the effect you need you may use `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled` so your html could look like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked readonly/></td>
```

Then for the above html the php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['chk'])) $chk = 1;
else $chk = 0;
```

should give you `1`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago. Regards :)

Answer (score 3):

A disabled form control will never send its data to the server, so PHP will never be able to read its data.

Consider using a hidden input instead.